# Error term in finite differences using Taylor's theorem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

y'all! For my ODEs class in college, we were asked to find the truncation error and round-off error(separately) for this given finite differences problem.

$f'(x) \approx$ $\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h}$

It says we should ignore the round-off errors in h,x,x+h, x+2h?

I am not too sure about the following things:

- Firstly, I thought these were the very terms the errors were coming from. So how can we just ignore these and still be able to compute the error?
- Secondly, I understand that the solution to this problem has to be when we expand this expression using the Taylor series, but I am not too sure how to expand it. The reason I say this is because usually when expanding a function of the form $f(x)$ using the Taylor series, we expand about some point a. But here the function to expand is of the form (x+2h) and (x+h), and I am not even sure which point we are expanding this function about.
- Thirdly, for the round-off error if we are to consider round-off error in each term in the numerator, how do we account for these, just add them up?
- Finally, if someone posts a solution the problem, can you please help me specifically with the Taylor expansions? Our Calculus 2 class did not cover it.

Also, am I able to find a finite difference approximation to the second derivative of f using this?

The way I thought about it was is that in the easiest case of finding second derivative using finite difference, we have that $f''(x) = \frac{f(x+h)+f(x-h)+2f(x)}{h^{2}}$. Should I just replace the values in the above term?

Answer (score 2):

We know from Taylor's theorem that
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k + O((x-a)^{n+1}), \quad x \rightarrow a,
\end{equation}
if $f$ is $n+1$ times differentiable in some interval containing $a$. Now let $x$ be fixed (the value at which you want to approximate the derivative of $f$), and we use the formula above with $x$ replaced by $x+h$ and $x+2h$, respectively, and with $a$ replaced by $x$ (so that $x-a = h$ and $x-a = 2h$, respectively). Thus we expand about the fixed $x$:
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x) &=& f(x),\\
f(x+h) &=& f(x) + f'(x) h + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) h^2 + \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(x) h^3 + O(h^4),\\
f(x+2h) &=& f(x) + f'(x) 2h  + \frac{1}{2} f''(x) 4h^2 + \frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(x) 8 h^3 + O(h^4),
\end{eqnarray}
for $h \rightarrow 0$. Now we form the finite difference
\begin{eqnarray}
-3f(x) +4f(x+h) -f(x+2h) &=& (-3+4-1)f(x) + (4-2)f'(x)h +\\
&& + (4-4)\frac{1}{2} f''(x) h^2 + (4-8)\frac{1}{6}f^{(3)}(x) h^3 + O(h^4)\\
&=& 2 f'(x) h - \frac{2}{3} f^{(3)}(x) h^3 + O(h^4)\\
&=& 2hf'(x) + O(h^3), \quad h \rightarrow 0.
\end{eqnarray}
Finally, dividing by $2h$, we obtain the difference quotient
\begin{equation}
\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h} = f'(x) + O(h^2), \quad h \rightarrow 0.
\end{equation}
Therefore, the given forward difference approximation for the first derivative of $f$ is second-order accurate.

Let us denote the forward difference quotient on the left-hand side by $g(h)$ ($x$ is fixed!). If we evaluate it using finite-precision arithmetic then we will compute a value $\tilde{g}(h) \neq g(h)$. If we consider round-off error only in the evaluation of $f$ at the three points (i. e. we evaluate a function $f_{\epsilon}$ instead of $f$, where $\epsilon$ denotes the machine precision), then we can estimate $|g(h) - \tilde{g}(h)| =$
\begin{eqnarray}
&& \left|\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h} - \frac{-3f_{\epsilon}(x)+4f_{\epsilon}(x+h)-f_{\epsilon}(x+2h)}{2h}\right|\\
&=& \left| \frac{-3(f(x)-f_{\epsilon}(x)) + 4(f(x+h)-f_{\epsilon}(x+h)) - (f(x+2h)-f_{\epsilon}(x+2h))}{2h} \right|\\
&\leq& \frac{3\epsilon + 4\epsilon + \epsilon}{2h} = \frac{4\epsilon}{h} = O(h^{-1}), \quad h \rightarrow 0.
\end{eqnarray}
The truncation error and the round-off error are usually split by using the triangle inequality:
\begin{equation}
e_h := |f'(x) - \tilde{g}(h)| \leq \underbrace{|f'(x) - g(h)|}_{\textrm{truncation error $O(h^2)$}} + \underbrace{|g(h)-\tilde{g}(h)|}_{\textrm{round-off error $O(h^{-1})$}}, \quad h \rightarrow 0,
\end{equation}
so that they can indeed be treated separately.

As $h \rightarrow 0$ the round-off error will eventually dominate, and this is exactly the behavior you should observe when you plot the approximation error $e_h$ (for specific $f$ and $x$) vs. $h$: in a log-log plot, the error will decrease first with slope $2$, but at some point will increase again with slope $-1$ due to the round-off error. I illustrate this here for $f(x) := \ln(x)$ at $x := 1$ ($f'(x) = 1$):

[image]

Comment: +1. I believe the randomness on the left leg of the graph is better captured in a dot plot with a much higher sampling density like I did in my answers in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2497660 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693958, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019573. With too few points one gets the impression that there is a well-defined function where in reality the floating point errors behave quasi-randomly.

Answer (score 1):

To the last point, you can write that expression as a combination of easier-to-recognize building blocks, iterated divided differences, 
$$
\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}-\frac{h^2}{2}\frac{f(x+2h)-3f(x+h)+3f(x)-f(x-h)}{h^3}.
$$
The first term is a second order approximation of the first derivative, and the second term is after the quadratic factor a third order difference quotient, thus at least an $O(h)$ approximation of $f'''(x)$, meaning a bounded expression.

Comment: Hey man, thanks! I think I get this, can you help me estimate the value of f''(x) no one else has yet helped me on it?

Comment: You missed the minus sign, $$\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}=f''(x)+\frac{h^2}{12}f^{(4)}(x)+\frac{h^4}{360}f^{(6)}(x)+...$$ is the second iteration of the difference quotient.

Comment: Do you think it is okay to apply finite-difference to the first derivative, and then we can simply replace the values of $f'(x)$ and $f'(x+h)$ in $\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$ with the values in the question?

Comment: You can do that, but usually these compositions have a less compact support or less than the maximum possible order for the support than formulas that are directly computed for the derivative in question.

Answer (score 1):

**Apply Taylor's Theorem**

Taylor's Theorem gives the two equations
$$
\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}2f''(x)+\int_0^hf'''(x+t)\frac{(h-t)^2}2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1a}\\
f(x+2h)&=f(x)+2hf'(x)+2h^2f''(x)+\int_0^{2h}f'''(x+t)\frac{(2h-t)^2}2\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
&\left|\,\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h}-f'(x)\,\right|\tag{2a}\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{2h}\left|\,4\int_0^hf'''(x+t)\frac{(h-t)^2}2\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_0^{2h}f'''(x+t)\frac{(2h-t)^2}2\,\mathrm{d}t\,\right|\tag{2b}\\
&\le\frac1{2h}\left(4\sup_{t\in[0,h]}|f'''(x+t)|\,\frac{h^3}6+\sup_{t\in[0,2h]}|f'''(x+t)|\,\frac{4h^3}3\right)\tag{2c}\\[6pt]
&\le h^2\sup_{t\in[0,2h]}|f'''(x+t)|\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2b)}$: apply $\text{(1a)}$ and $\text{(1b)}$ to $\text{(2a)}$
$\text{(2c)}$: $\int_0^h\frac{(h-t)^2}2\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac16h^3$ and $\int_0^{2h}(2h-t)\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac43h^3$
$\text{(2d)}$: $\sup\limits_{t\in[0,h]}|f'''(x+t)|\le\sup\limits_{t\in[0,2h]}|f'''(x+t)|$

Thus,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\left|\,\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h}-f'(x)\,\right|
\le h^2\sup_{t\in[0,2h]}|f'''(x+t)|}\tag3
$$

---

**Extension of the Mean Value Theorem**

Let
$$
\begin{align}
g(x+ht)
&=\left(f(x)+\left(hf'(x)+\tfrac32f(x)\right)t\right)\frac{(t-1)(t-2)}2\\
&-f(x+h)\,t^2(t-2)+f(x+2h)\,\frac{t^2(t-1)}4
\end{align}\tag4
$$
Then it is easy to verify that
$$
\begin{align}
g(x)&=f(x)&g'(x)&=f'(x)\\
g(x+h)&=f(x+h)&g(x+2h)&=f(x+2h)
\end{align}\tag5
$$
Equations $(5)$ implies
$$
(-3I+4S_h-S_{2h}-2hD)(f-g)(x)=0\tag6
$$
where $S_h$ is the shift operator: $S_hf(x)=f(x+h)$; and $D$ is differentiation: $Df(x)=f'(x)$.

Since
$$
(-3I+4S_h-S_{2h}-2hD)\left(1,x,x^2,x^3\right)=\left(0,0,0,-4h^3\right)\tag7
$$
and $g(x)$ is a cubic polynomial, we get that
$$
(-3I+4S_h-S_{2h}-2hD)g(x)=-\tfrac23g'''(\xi)\,h^3\tag8
$$
for all $\xi$ (since $g'''$ is a constant).

According to $(5)$,
$$
\begin{align}
(f-g)(x)&=0\\
(f-g)(x+h)&=0\\
(f-g)(x+2h)&=0
\end{align}\tag9
$$
[image]

According to $(5)$ and Rolle's Theorem applied to $(9)$:
$$
\begin{align}
(f-g)'(x)&=0\\
(f-g)'(\xi_1)&=0&x\lt\xi_1\lt x+h\\
(f-g)'(\xi_2)&=0&x+h\lt\xi_1\lt x+2h
\end{align}\tag{10}
$$
[image]

Applying Rolle's Theorem to $(10)$:
$$
\begin{align}
(f-g)''(\xi_3)&=0&x\lt\xi_3\lt\xi_1\\
(f-g)''(\xi_4)&=0&\xi_1\lt\xi_4\lt\xi_2
\end{align}\tag{11}
$$
[image]

Applying Rolle's Theorem to $(11)$:
$$
\begin{align}
(f-g)'''(\xi_5)&=0&\xi_3\lt\xi_5\lt\xi_4
\end{align}\tag{12}
$$
[image]

Therefore, for some $\xi_5$ between $x$ and $x+2h$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
-\tfrac23f'''(\xi_5)h^3
&=-\tfrac23g'''(\xi_5)\,h^3\tag{13}\\
&=(-3I+4S_h-S_{2h}-2hD)g(x)\tag{14}\\[3pt]
&=(-3I+4S_h-S_{2h}-2hD)f(x)\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(13)$: apply $(12)$
$(14)$: apply $(8)$
$(15)$: apply $(5)$

Rewriting $(15)$ gives
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{-3f(x)+4f(x+h)-f(x+2h)}{2h}-f'(x)=-\tfrac13f'''(\xi)\,h^2}\tag{16}
$$
for some $\xi\in(x,x+2h)$.